# Accessing contact data in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have gone through msdn article "Accessing contact and calendar data for Windows Phone"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286414(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CreatingtheApplicationProject

```
<TextBlock Text="phone numbers" Margin="12,12,0,0"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PhoneNumbers}" Height="60"  Margin="36,0,0,0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Kind, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text=":  " />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="pno" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=PhoneNumber, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

In the above XAML Phone Number is dynamic bound to the TextBlock Name="pno"(Named myself not in msdn code)

I want to get the Phone number in a variable say Phone_no .How ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bind to the default ContactPhoneNumber (don't use the IEnumerable called PhoneNumbers for binding).

Create your own class to hold phone number data

```
public class MyContactPhoneNumber
{
    public PhoneNumber Phone_no {get; set;}
    //other properties you want
}
```

and create a new collection of those custom contact phone numbers

```
List<MyContactPhoneNumber> myNumbers = new List<MyContactPhoneNumber>();
```

Then in a foreach loop copy data from PhoneNumbers to a list of MyContactPhoneNumber

```
foreach (var number in PhoneNumbers)
    myNumbers.Add(new MyContactPhoneNumber
        {
           //...copy all properties here, for example Phone_no = number.PhoneNumber
        });
```

And then bind that to the UI

```
ListOfNumbers.ItemsSource = myNumbers;


// and in XAML

<ListBox Name="ListOfNumbers" Height="60"  Margin="36,0,0,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="pno" Text="{Binding Path=Phone_no, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If you want two way binding support and better binding support overall, use ObservableCollection instead of a List and implement INotifyPropertyChanged in MyContactPhoneNumber class.